# How to group distinct records in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I have the following data in my Elasticsearch index:

```
{
  "title": "Hello from elastic",
  "name": "ABC",
  "j_id": "1",
  "date": '2021-03-02T12:29:31.356514'
},
{
  "title": "Hello from elastic",
  "name": "PQR",
  "j_id": "1",
  "date": '2021-03-02T12:29:31.356514'
},
{
  "title": "Hello from elastic",
  "name": "XYZ",
  "j_id": "2",
  "date": '2021-03-02T12:29:31.356514'
},
{
  "title": "Hello from elastic",
  "name": "MNO",
  "j_id": "3",
  "date": '2021-03-02T12:29:31.356514'
}
```

Now I want to get unique records on the basis of the `id`.

The expected output is:

```
{
    "1": [{
      "title": "Hello from elastic",
      "name": "ABC",
      "j_id": "1",
      "date": '2021-03-02T12:29:31.356514'
    },
    {
      "title": "Hello from elastic",
      "name": "PQR",
      "j_id": "1",
      "date": '2021-03-02T12:29:31.356514'
    }],
    "2": [{
      "title": "Hello from elastic",
      "name": "XYZ",
      "j_id": "2",
      "date": '2021-03-02T12:29:31.356514'
    }],
    "3": [{
      "title": "Hello from elastic",
      "name": "MNO",
      "j_id": "3",
      "date": '2021-03-02T12:29:31.356514'
    }]
  }
```

I tried an aggregate query but it's giving me only the counts.
Also, I want to include latest record in my response.

1. How can I get sorted, unique records from Elasticsearch grouped by the `id`?
2. I want latest inserted data first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a minimal mapping covering the `date` and `j_id` fields:

```
PUT myindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "j_id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "date": {
        "type": "date"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

you can leverage a [`terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) whose [sub-aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html#run-sub-aggs) is an ordered [`top_hits` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html):

```
POST myindex/_search?filter_path=aggregations.*.buckets.key,aggregations.*.buckets.sorted_hits.hits.hits._source
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_j_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "j_id",
        "size": 10,
        "order": {
          "max_date": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_date": {
          "max": {
            "field": "date"
          }
        },
        "sorted_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 10,
            "sort": [
              {
                "date": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The URL parameter [`filter_path`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#common-options-response-filtering) reduces the response body to closely mimic your required format:

```
{
  "aggregations" : {
    "by_j_id" : {
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "1",        
          "sorted_hits" : {
            "hits" : {
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_source" : {
                    "title" : "Hello from elastic",
                    "name" : "ABC",
                    "j_id" : "1",
                    "date" : "2021-03-02T12:29:31.356514"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "_source" : {
                    "title" : "Hello from elastic",
                    "name" : "PQR",
                    "j_id" : "1",
                    "date" : "2021-03-02T12:29:31.356514"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "2",
          "sorted_hits" : {
            "hits" : {
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_source" : {
                    "title" : "Hello from elastic",
                    "name" : "XYZ",
                    "j_id" : "2",
                    "date" : "2021-03-02T12:29:31.356514"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "3",
          "sorted_hits" : {
            "hits" : {
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_source" : {
                    "title" : "Hello from elastic",
                    "name" : "MNO",
                    "j_id" : "3",
                    "date" : "2021-03-02T12:29:31.356514"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Joe, This solution working for me but I want latest inserted data first.

Comment: OK that wasn't mentioned in the question ;) I've updated my answer -- the trick is to add a `max` aggregation on the `date` field and sort the `terms` with it. Hope it helps.

Comment: Can I add pagination in above query?